# Listview based on Mysql when item clicked returns the first Mysql record

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I populate a listview from Mysql , I click on Listview item and display details of particular record. My problem is that even if record_id is passed nicely from listview the details are shown always for the first record. How to overcome this problem? what to check first?  The php part is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["po"]) &&  isset($_POST["ng"])) 
{

$id = $_POST["id"];
$po= $_POST["po"];
$ng= $_POST["ng"];

$sql = "UPDATE names SET po=po + "$po", ng=ng + "$ng"  WHERE id = "$poll_id"";
```

The Async part of passing id is :

```
List<NameValuePair> params2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            // Note that product details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_details, "GET", params2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making a GET request to the given url_details variable link. I guess this should be a POST request.

Furthermore, if you run into any trouble, you can var_dump($_POST); in PHP to dump all the variables for debugging purposes.

I also notice that you take $_POST variables and set them directly into SQL statements.
This is considered to be a bad thing, because this approach is vulnerable to something called SQL-injection.

See the following link for more information about SQL-injection.
http://wiki.hashphp.org/Validation

Please let me know if the problem is resolved this way.

Comment: It s not working with POST neither , about $_POST any suggestion on the above?

Comment: It isn't nice, but should work, but since you are using a jsonParser to do a POST request, you can't really see a var_dump() in there.

You could consider doing sidetrack debugging

    mail('johndoe@example.com', 'debuginfo', print_r($_POST, true));

This way you e-mail yourself with the contents of the $_POST array, to see which ones are missing (I would say the 'po' and 'ng' variables.

I would put the mail statement above the if, since if those variables are missing, the if statement is never true.